how relative width is calculated in css
i am beginner in web development,
i want to make my home-page element (div) to flex column in which first element is a flex row container which again contains a flex container div (icons)
when i did this, i found that width of container containing img elements is not decreasing to fit all imgs why it is happening ?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0px;
    }

    #home-page {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    * {
      border: 1px solid;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    nav {
      display: flex;
      height: 100px;
    }


    #icons {
      display: flex;
    }

    img {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="home-page">
    <nav>
      <div id="icons">
        <div><img src="/images/icons/menu-icon.png" alt=""></div>
        <div><img src="/images/icons/search-icon.png" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

here is the image of output

also explain me that how the width and height of any element is calculated when there are all relative sizes (percentage,etc.)
when i set the width or height to a pixel value then i worked, but i want to know why it is not working in relative size (i want to make most of sizes relative so that my website become responsive)

The relative percentage width / height units are calculated relative to the nearest absolutely sized parent element. Say for a div element to take the 50% of its parent, parent element of that div must be sized absolutely (in pixels, viewport units, em, etc...).
I would advise you to check w3schools' references for CSS Units: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.php
Also to container div #icons to cover its children properly, you can try to assign actual width values to its children img elements.
